# Rails controller action result in Faye

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, faye

I have a rails application with Faye gem. My rails application is divided into two engines. One of the engines has a controller. This controller contains a method called Index that can get data from the database. This method uses a JSON view with a help of jbuilder gem.

So the question is whenever a user subscribes to the faye channel, I would like to push the result of this controller method through this channel to the user with JSON format. How can I do this?

Here is my source code:

```
#/faye.ru

require 'faye'
Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')
app = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 25)
run app



#/engines/restaurant/app/controllers/restaurant/menu_controller.rb

class Restaurant::MenuController < RestaurantController

  def index
    @categories = Category.where("status" => true)
  end

end



#/engines/restaurant/app/views/restaurant/menu/index.json.jbuilder

json.categories @categories do |category|
  json.id category.id
  json.name category.name
  json.image category.image.url
end



#/config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'restaurant/home#index'

  mount Restaurant::Engine => '/', as: 'restaurant'
end
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: How can I push the result from the controller action to the user through the channel using FAYE in JSON format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advice you to use gem [private_pub](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub) to work with faye (it's very simple just look at [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub)). With private_pub you can touch your action in connection callback in js code. Simple example (how to connect and config private_pub - look at [cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub) or at [gem's github page](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub)):

Create action in any your controller for subscribtion (for example)

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  def subscription
    @subscription = nil
    # channel_id is your identificator of channel
    @subscription = PrivatePub.subscription(channel: "/channel/#{channel_id}") 
    render json: @subscription.to_json(root: false)
  end
end
```

In your js (if you use jquery):

```
$.getJSON('/controller_path/subscription', function (data) {
  // you can call your action here to load any data you want
  $.getJSON('your action', function(data) { 
    //your code here 
  });
  PrivatePub.sign(data);
  PrivatePub.subscribe(data.channel, function(data, channel) {
    // your code here to process data from faye
  });
});
```